# Symfony2 User permission managment

Tags: symfony, user-permissions

I come to you because I have a little concern about the management of users and their Permissions with Symfony2.

Let me explain:

I set up the FOSUserBundle:

What I'd like to do now is a rights management. I have an entity 'Post'.
I have users with roles specified below.

```
ROLE_GUEST -  VIEW,RATE
ROLE_USER  -  VIEW,CREATE,RATE,EDIT_OWN
ROLE_EDITOR - VIEW,CREATE,RATE,EDIT,DELETE
```

I want to set permission to each roles for performing certain actions.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your necessity correctly you want to have a security layer based on those roles. You can do this in may ways:

The symfony default way - 
you can configure the security layer of symfony like in the example below

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
# ...
access_control:
    - { path: ^/post/view, roles: VIEW }
    - { path: ^/post/rate, roles: RATE }
# etc
```

This will take care of route access control. More info on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html

For more complex roles like EDIT_OWN, you can take the direct approach

```
if (!$post->isAuthor($this->getUser())) {
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('EDIT', $post);

    // or without the shortcut:
    //
    // use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
    // ...
    //
    // if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('edit', $post)) {
    //    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    // }
} else {
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('EDIT_OWN', $post);
}
```

For all this and more you can check the symfony site http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html

For even more advanced roles or ACL requirement also take a look here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html and at the authorization voters https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html#voters

In the 4 links I provided in this post you should find all you need to implement RBAC as well as ACL. You can also find information about some annotations you may want to use. Also there are some extensions to the symfony security layer that may come in handy depending on the symfony version you are working on like JMS\SecurityExtraBundle.

Hope this help,

Alexandru Cosoi

Comment: For specific stuff, like edit but not delete on same entity, isn't it better to use [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) to check permission?

Comment: @Bart Bartoman It all depend on your app architecture. You can restrict an action in various place of your app. It all depends on the complexity and the information required in order to decide if the action is allowed or not. So, if let say you are developing rest api you can cut access starting from routing level based on roles, but if you want ACL stuff then you need to first retrieve the data objects that the ACL is controlling, and so, in this case voters can be the way to do it. That is why i just mentioned voters at the end in case he required more complex restriction rules.

Comment: In the end, in order to optimize, best thing to do is restrict access as soon as you know for sure that it is restricted. In practice i only used voters when i want to restrict rly low level stuff, with complex restriction rules, like editing the property of an entity. But you can extend to voters from the direct approach easily, if needed.

Comment: @Bart Bartoman Also you should try and keep your app functionalities as simple as possible to keep your app entropy low. So instead of asking a complex question like :can a user edit but not delete, you can ask if a use cand edit. when he tries to edit, and if a use can delete when he tries to delete. so you can reduce a complex question to 2 less complex questions.